# How can I repair this Ikea light fixture that seems to be missing parts?

Tags: electrical, lighting

We found this chandelier at IKEA in the as-is section (apparently formerly a floor model), and as it seemed to be in perfect condition, 50% off the retail price seemed like a good deal. Unfortunately, we didn't realize it was missing a vital part: the ceiling mount AND a wiring adapter (as seen in [step #3 in these instructions](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/soder-chandelier-armed__AA-503235-1_pub.PDF)). So basically what I have is an unmarked two-stranded wire (the connector was removed from the light fixture's cord as well), and no way to connect them to the ceiling box.

I purchased a stand-alone canopy kit, which can replace the missing canopy mount, but I cannot seem to figure out where to find a power adapter to connect to my ceiling wires and the light fixture's wires. I've figured out that I definitely need something through trial and error -- connecting the wires directly to the ceiling lines results in blown bulbs (with the wires tried both ways). I may just need to know what that little cube thingy is actually called, so I can look it up.

It also occurs to me that this could very well NOT be the problem... The quick connect boxes I'm seeing don't actually have any electrical bits in them, they're just faster than using wire nuts. Maybe the wires in my ceiling are screwy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The bulbs are not rated for line voltage, and that box is likely some form of [Rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier) and/or step down transformer.  I'd follow the instructions on page 3 of the installation guide.

[image]

---

From [IKEA SÖDER Chandelier, 7-armed](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/50209158/):

> #### Care instructions
>
> Halogen bulb G4 12V 10W

Comment: There would be no reason for it to be a rectifier unless it was driving LEDs or CFLs. It wouldn't make much sense for LEDs unless it also stepped the voltage down to a lower voltage. ( All a rectifier does is turn AC voltage source into a DC voltage source of nearly the same amplitude. )

Comment: Sorry @BradGilbert I misspoke a bit, and assumed that folks would understand that a rectifier circuit would also have some way to step down the voltage. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: The only reason for it to have a rectifier is if it uses a [switching power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply). In which case it would be more appropriately called a power supply. I would have edited the post to just say "*some form of low voltage power supply, possibly just a [step down transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer).*"

Comment: Presumably you meant "DC power supply," not "rectifier."  A rectifier is one part of a DC power supply, but on its own it's not useful for anything that would be mentioned on this site.

Comment: Nitpickers! What is a DC power supply if not a step down transformer and a rectifier wired together?  What I'm trying to say, is that it could be a step down transformer, but could also include a rectifier.  The point however, is moot, since we can only speculate what the box was.  The only way to know for sure is to contact IKEA.

Comment: A power supply also requires *at the very least* a reservoir capacitor as a filter; but regardless, why would you use a term only an electrical engineer would know when there is a more commonly-known (and more correct) term available?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Cuz that's how I roll. The image is the "real" answer, the text is just useless filler.

Answer (score 2):

This is the missing piece, it's a transformer.
[image: Long view of transformer]
[image: Transformer label]

Comment: It should be quite easy to use an alternative transformer.